# Syntax Error of function variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using node version 12.22.6.

I don't understand, how this code is wrong.
I'm probably missing some important basic thing, but just cannot figure it out.

```
const change_vars = (var) => {
    console.log(var + " is a " + typeof(var) + "\n");
}

const variables = [
    42,
    "42",
    {number: 42},
    {},
    true,
    undefined
]

variables.forEach(var => change_vars(var));
```

> node vars.js

> $ SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'

Comment: "var" is a reserved keyword in JS - you can't use it for a variable name (and function parameters are just a special type of variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a reserved word to name your variables, you can find the full list here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar

But some examples include:

```
break
case
catch
class
const
continue
debugger
default
delete
do
else
export
extends
finally
for
function
if
import
in
instanceof
new
return
super
switch
this
throw
try
typeof
var
void
while
with
yield
```

Long story short makes sure your variables are not named the same as the reserved words.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

`var` is a reserved keyword in javascript. Use another variable name.

Comment: Thank you! I'll use another name!

Answer (score 0):

You can't name your variable `var` as that is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#reserved_keywords_as_of_ecmascript_2015) in javascript.

(Unrelated: I recommend using camel-case for variables; `changeVars` instead of `change_vars`)

Comment: Thank you! I'll change the variable and the function name!

Answer (score 0):

`var` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, you will have to rename your variable to something else: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#keywords

Comment: Thank you so much!!